# Firebase Crashlytics Migration and View Dashboard

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

How can I view the Crashltyics dashboard content in Firebase for a migrated app?

I completed the migration steps in Fabric but Firebase keeps prompting me to migrate. The app is showing as migrated in Fabric. However, the Crashlytics dashboard that I am supposed to see is not showing. Instead, it keeps prompting me to migrate.

I selected "Yes, migrate my Fabric app to Firebase" again and it brings me back to Fabric.  Fabric says "migrated" for the app in question.

Also, in Fabric, it appears I am supposed "link" the app with Fabric and Firebase. However, there is no icon to "drag and drop" since the app is already migrated. It will not let me drag the existing icon again. I don't know if this is what is causing Firebase to think the app is not migrated yet.

Is there a way to manually tell Firebase that the apps are migrated in Fabric? I would like to view the Crashlytics dashboard.

Any suggestions?

[image: Firebase Crashlytics]
[image: Fabric Prompt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved through the support(at)fabric(dot)io support channel. The developers app was previously migrated by a separate person in their org. They needed to be given permission by the user that linked the app through the Firebase Console.